Setup new SOLANA RPC Server
I would like to start a SOLANA RPC Server and I have some doubts:

When is the "--no-snapshot-fetch" parameter used? Only at the first synchronization of the RPC? Is it possible an example of parameterization for a new RPC for the first synchronization and after?
Can several IP addresses be used for the SOLANA VALIDATOR service in such a way that the UDP communication is on one IP address, and the port and listen on another IP address?
Why when starting SOLANA VALIDATOR I no longer have TCP traffic on the IP address but only UDP. Internet bandwidth is only used 30% or less.
Thank you



The --no-snapshot-fetch is used when you want to control the synchronization process manually, especially during the first sync or if you want the node to build up its own snapshot rather than pulling one from the network.

Yes, it is possible to configure the solana validator to use different IP addresses for different network functions. UDP communication on one IP and port listening on another IP can be achieved by specifying different IP addresses in the configuration.

When Solana validator starts, it primarily uses UDP for gossip and transaction processing, leading to minimal TCP traffic at startup, with bandwidth usage reflecting the network's current activity level.


Read the solana documentation for more info => https://solana.com/docs/
